# ssjs to save multiple documents

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

With the onclick event of a button I would like to save multiple documents, but only the last one gets saved.

```
    <xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="tg"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
```

and in the onclick event of the button :

```
... 
while (re.next()) { 

        document1.replaceItemValue("TGARKD",tgarkd);
        document1.replaceItemValue("TGKDOM",tgkdom);
        document1.replaceItemValue("TGARGR",tgargr);
        document1.replaceItemValue("TGDLGR",tgdlgr);
        document1.save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create multiple Documents in the NSF, you'll need to use backend classes. The DominoDocument datasource is tied to a single backend document. `var doc = document1.getDocument(true)` will get a handle on the (first) backend document, then in your loop use

```
var doc2 = database.createDocument();
doc.copyAllItems(doc2, true);
doc2.save(true, false);
```

Comment: for the record: `getDocument(true)` calls have side effects in combination with file attachments - may be missing in saved document.

Comment: Maybe an alternative, because we're talking about getting the document immediately after save, is `database.getDocumentByUNID()`, using the newly-set unid from the DominoDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could define your data source inside a repeat control and bind the fields to that one. Then outside the repeat you call `save()` which saves all data sources